# Need Help taking data from column B only when it has a certain value in column A to another sheet.

Tags: google-sheets

Have two columns, column A will have 3 statuses. "Pending, Inspecting, Done"

Column B will have Car Vin Numbers. Need advice on writing a formula using the google formula to import or "grab" the VIN numbers that has Status "Pending" only.

I looked in the documentation, the closest I see there is VLOOKUP but only returns one value. Need the entire column checked and grab all VIN numbers with "Pending" Statuses. Any Ideas?

Just to start, I understand this could be accomplished via Google App Scripts. I'm slowly learning how to use it but I for now, I am using the formulas provided by google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add in a new sheet on the same doc and use the filter function:

```
=filter('Sheet1'!A1:B10,'Sheet1'!A1:A10="pending")
```